# How to add field to custom post type endpoint

Tags: custom-post-types, rest-api, endpoints

I have an endpoint in this address:

```
example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/myendpoint
```

I want to add a field to the endpoint with these codes:

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'create_api_posts_meta_field' );
 
function create_api_posts_meta_field() {    
    register_rest_field( 
        'myendpoint',
        'post-meta-fields',
        array(
           'get_callback'    => 'get_post_meta_for_api',
        )
    );
}
 
function get_post_meta_for_api( ) {
    $hello="Hello";
    return $hello;
}
```

but it doesn't work. Please tell me whats wrong with my codes.

Comment: Your code seems fine, so how exactly is it not working - did you see any error, or your custom REST field doesn't appear in the response? Are you sure the post type *slug* is correct - which in the question is `myendpoint`?

Comment: Hi, myendpoint is existed and working correctly. I want to add "post-meta-fields" to it. but it doesn't show "post-meta-fields" in this address: example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/myendpoint

Comment: Can you edit your question and include the post type registration code?